# How to select an item (li) within a list (ul) through Selenium WebDriver and C# - timeout when locating

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Can't seem to select a list item `<li>` from an unsorted list `<ul>`, using WebDriver. A timeout is received when locating.

HTML :

```html
   <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="btn btn-block btn-dropdown-white" data-ng-class="{'has-error': updateFormTemplate.gender.$invalid }" dropdown="">
                        <input id="hdnGender" name="gender" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-maxlength" data-ng-model="updateInfo.gender" nl-input="" nl-validation-type="'gender'" nl-required="true" maxlength="1" nl-action-button="update" nl-on-enter-action="update" type="hidden">
                        <button type="button" name="genderButton" class="btn btn-lg form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding ng-isolate-scope ng-touched" dropdown-toggle="" data-ng-model="updateInfo.gender" nl-input="" nl-validation-hidden="hdnGender" nl-action-button="update" nl-on-enter-action="update" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Ansprache <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li data-ng-click="updateInfo.gender = ''">Gender</li>
                            <li data-ng-click="updateInfo.gender = 'M'" class="">Male</li>
                            <li data-ng-click="updateInfo.gender = 'F'">Female</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="display-inline-block inner-top-xxs" data-ng-class="{'has-error': updateFormTemplate.gender.$invalid }">
                        <span data-ng-show="updateFormTemplate.gender.$invalid" class="help-block ng-hide">Please select gender</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My code:

```
IList <IWebElement> dropDownMenues = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("dropdown-menu")); //Populates all drop down menues
IList<IWebElement> selectedGender = dropDownMenues[1].FindElements(By.TagName("li")); //Populate drop down items
//dropDownMenues[1].Click(); - This code doens't expand the drop down menu
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/button")).Click(); //This code opens the drop down
selectedGender[1].Click(); //Here's where I get the timeout
```

After many different variations, I keep getting the same - list item isn't selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the solution was very simple and not what pops into mind...
All I had to do is **update my ChromeDriver.exe** to the latest version (it was 8 months old) - and I was able to find all elements that caused timeout before.

I've updated some Selenium packages in my Visual Studio not so long ago which most likely caused this situation, but failed to remember that the ChromeDriver should be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To click on any of the `<li>` items within the `<ul>` as the elements are [Angular](https://angular.io/) elements you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and to click on the option with text as **Male** you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-lg form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding ng-isolate-scope ng-touched' and @name='genderButton']"))).Click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-lg form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding ng-isolate-scope ng-touched' and @name='genderButton']/ul//li[contains(@data-ng-click, 'gender') and text()='Male']"))).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB, but I'm still getting a timeout when trying to click the <li> element... It's unreachable and I can't seem to bypass

Comment: Also, it's an AngularJS single page application. Drop down box items are hidden till clicked to expand... Page isn't refreshed of course.

Comment: @Eyal Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB, but I'm still getting a timeout.
- The 1st click - I had to change the XPath to Tejas Jagtap's XPath above - box is expanded.
- The 2nd click still gets a timeout... With your provided XPath, or Tejas Jagtap's one. This timeout is a 60 seconds timeout - meaning that search didn't conduct properly...?

Comment: @Eyal Actually, there is an issue with the HTML you have provided. The `<button>` tag never got closed where as the parent `<div>` got closed. Can you crosscheck if the HTML is exact as it is?

Comment: @ DebanjanB - You're very right!
I missed some expanding (working with Firebug). Updated above

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done using two clicks.
Do 1st click on xpath :

```
//*[@name='genderButton']
```

Then 2nd click on xpath :

```
//*[@class='dropdown-menu']/li[2]
```

P.S: use the webdriver wait beforehand so that you give time for the element to load.

Comment: Thanks Tejas, but while the 1st click works just fine (expands the selection) - I'm getting a timeout trying to click li[2]... It's unreachable for some reason I can't figure how to bypass

Comment: Also, it's an AngularJS single page application. Drop down box items are hidden till clicked to expand... Page isn't refreshed of course.

Comment: I hope you have used enough wait after clicking on 1st dropdown click.

Comment: Also, once try with this xpath for 2nd click: 
`//li[contains(text(),'Male')]`